# Проблема с использованием старых тем оформления андроид

Tags: java, android

Пишу приложение на андроид. Возникла проблема, когда я хотел использовать старую тему оформления для моего приложения. Выдает ошибку:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: От какой активити вы наследете свои активити?

Comment: appCompatActivity. Уже понял, что в этом ошибка была. За то теперь другая проблема возникла. Мне нужно снизить размер апк файла. Вроде тему оформления поставил попроще. А вес каким был, таким и остался. Не могли бы Вы подсказать из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: @lemuur, оформление/тема приложения никак не связана с размером apk файла, т.к. любое оформление/тема берут ресурсы из одного источника/библиотеки.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Не могли бы Вы тогда подсказать, от чего это зависит? Просто код у меня совсем малюсенький. Пробовал просто новый проект создать и скомпилировать его. Размер тот же самый.

Comment: Ну подскажите хоть кто-нибудь пожалуйста. Мне очень нужно сжать апк в 10 раз. Ну неужели никто не знает ответа?

Comment: Ну, можно попробовать выкинуть все библиотеки, в т.ч. support. Но насколько это поможет - хз. Вы ж не рассказываете что за 10р - с 100Мб до 10Мб или с 1Мб до 100Кб...

Comment: Извиняюсь. С 1мб до 100кб нужно сжать

Comment: Удаление support библиотеки из апк привело к поломке программы. Ничего не выполняется. Без support никак не получается

Comment: По проблеме "поломки программы" без библиотеки поддержки создайте новый вопрос, приложите лог при "поломке" и всю необходимую информацию. Этот вопрос никак не связан с вашей второй проблемой и здесь обсуждаться не будет.

Comment: Все понял. Спасибо большое. Создам новый вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для "старых" тем - таких, как `Theme`, `Holo`, ваши активити должны наследоваться от "старых" базовых активити - `Activity`, `FragmentActivity` и тд., но не от активити, требующих наличие  библиотеки поддержки `AppCompat` ( и соответственно темы `Theme.AppCompat`) -  `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. В этом разобрался уже. Только вот проблемма размера приложения так и осталась. Я пробовал просто скомпилировать новый проект без какого-либо кода. Размеры у моего приложения и у нового проекта одинаковые. Подскажите пожалуйста, как уменьшить размер приложения. с 1мб до 100 кб.

Comment: Этот ресурс работает не так, как вы себе представляете - это база знаний, для повторного использования в будущем людьми с аналогичными проблемами, а не персональные консультации по вашим личным проблемам. Другие пользователи не будут тратить время на поиск решения аналогичной проблемы, а получат готовое решение. По другой проблеме создавайте другой вопрос.

Comment: Все понял. Спасибо большое. Так и сделаю.